# Oracleclient requires oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Hi have oracle 12 instqlled in the server but facing the error

> system.data.oracleclient requires oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.

I already installed oracle client 12
And addes the Authenticated Users[Add Authenticated User](http://system.data.oracleclient%20requires%20oracle%20client%20software%20version%208.1.7%20or%20greater.)

But still face the same error

Comment: Check you PATH variable. Which OCI library (oci.dll) is first in your PATH? Make sure it's 12c client library.

Comment: `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet?redirectedfrom=MSDN) for ages. Perhaps your client it 64-bit. `System.Data.OracleClient` exist only for 32-bit, i.e. this will not work.

Comment: Bjarte Brandt what do you mean. Sorry i dont understand which to check